# Distance of point from a polygon

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I want to calculate distance from point to a polygon.

My code for getting distance of point to a line is as follows:

```
 float px,py,something,u;
                px=x2-x1;
                py=y2-y1;

                something = px*px + py*py;

                u =  ((x - x1) * px + (y - y1) * py) /(something);


                if( u > 1)
                u = 1;
                else if (u < 0)
                u = 0;

                float xx = x1 + u * px;
                float yy = y1 + u * py;

                float dx = xx - x;
                float dy = yy - y;

                float dist= (float)Math.sqrt((double)dx*dx +(double) dy*dy);
```

The point could be on inside or outside the polygon. I am unable to found any usefull example to find distance of polygon from point.

Answer (score 0):

It does not surprise me that you cannot find this information. Polygons have finite area, which means to calculate distance from them you need to pick a point somewhere on the polygon to use as your reference. The simplest solution would be to use some measure of center for the polygon and test against that, then it could be as simple as using euclidean distance. If it helps, when you're dealing with something OpenGL considers a polygon, then polygons can be thought of as an ordered collection of points existing in the same plane -- this should simplify the process of finding the center.

For a more accurate measure of distance, you might want the distance to the closest point on the polygon. If you continue to treat the polygon as an arbitrary collection of edges this is quite complicated, but if you replace it with some simpler geometry (i.e. a bounding circle, square or triangle) you can greatly simplify things. The example I mentioned above can be extended to give you the distance from the exterior of a bounding circle by subtracting the radius from the distance to the center of the polygon.

Comment: i have taken centroid of polygon and then calculate distance from centroid to point but i am not getting cirrect distance